# Passing FCM subscription details to a Flutter web view

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutterwebviewplugin

No idea if this is possible. Essentially we have a number of web apps but we have a requirement to create a native mobile app which can act as a sort of hub to access the relevant apps in one place.

This is mostly functional in a small amount of time - I’ve gone from never developing an app to learning Dart to having something fairly functional in around a week - Flutter (and Dart, incidentally) is fantastic.

An additional feature we would like is to be able to send push notifications for certain events from the web app servers to the app itself. I assume we would need to associate our web app user accounts with FCM/device subscription keys.

Is there a way for the web views themselves to trigger the notification subscription process? Or can we pass the relevant info from the app to the web view so the web apps can then store that info on the server?

Hope that makes sense...

Thanks for any advice.